# Polymer issue with dropping a value into an attribute

Tags: html, polymer

So I have been trying to put together a custom storage element with Polymer which uses the polymer-localforage element inside it. The local forage element requires that you set it's name attribute and so I thought that I could simply pass the "name" attribute or "id" attribute from my custom element over to the local forage element in my template, but it doesn't work. To make sure I wasn't doing something wrong I did a custom element which just inserts the "name" attribute of the root into the "name" attribute of a div inside the template tag but that doesn't work either.

```
<dom-module id="x-custom">   
 <template>
   <div name="{{name}}">Hello {{name}}</div>
 </template>
</dom-module>
```

and the script

```
Polymer({

   is: 'x-custom',
   properties:{
     "name": {
       type: String
     }
   }

 });
```

if I use the element

```
<x-custom name="foo" />
```

What I then get is

```
<div class="style-scope x-custom">Hello foo</div>
```

No name attribute at all, not even a blank one.

How can I drop a template value into an attribute of a child element?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding $ at the end of attributes as below.

```
<dom-module id="x-custom">   
 <template>
   <div name$="{{name}}">Hello {{name}}</div>
 </template>
</dom-module>
```

The Polymer docs refer to this as [annotated attribute binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding).